# CPQ - In Quote line editor, when I manually enter a start date, it always updates itself to be a previous date, why is that happening

Tags: cpq

In quote line editor in CPQ, when I manually enter a start date (not through date picker), it always changes back to a previous date.

For example, if I enter 11/01/2019, it changes to 10/01/2019 right away when I click away. Why is this happening and is there a configuration we can try to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this when the user's computer timezone is different from their timezone set in Salesforce. For example, we had a US user travel to Australia and it started happening for him.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue to Salesforce: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JX1fQAG . Salesforce has just notified us that this issue has been resolved